Azure Functions: Error configuring services in an external startup class. Grpc.AspNetCore.Server
I am trying to run a function project using VS2022 but I am getting the following error:

Error configuring services in an external startup class.
Error configuring services in an external startup class. Grpc.AspNetCore.Server: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
A host error has occurred during startup operation '35009c5d-73af-433c-9251-90a6bdfd8a12'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error configuring services in an external startup class. Grpc.AspNetCore.Server: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

It is asking for version 7.0.0.0 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing. But this version does not exist and this lib is depreciated. I do not have a direct NuGet reference for it in the project file either.
I believe it might be an environment issue with VS2022 as the same project runs on a colleague's machine. I tried updating VS2022 (to version 17.12.3) and updating all NuGet packages.
I have also tried deleting my local repo and re-cloning.
I also tried including the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing package even though it is deprecated.

what version of Grpc.AspNetCore.Server are you using?

the 'Grpc.AspNetCore.Server' is not explicitly in my dependencies, i.e., I have not explicitly included in my libraries. It seems to be a dependence of another library.
